# Convergence of Lebesgue integrals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration, convergence-divergence

I am sitting on this multiple-choice question and I cannot answer it, nor say if it is right or wrong:

Given non-negative, Lebesgue-integrable functions $f,f_k\colon E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ with $\displaystyle\forall x \in E\setminus N: \lim_{k \to \infty}f_k(x)=f(x)$, where $\lambda(N)=0$, $E,N \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\int_E f_k(x) d\lambda=\int_E f(x) d\lambda$.

Is it always true that $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\int_E |f-f_k(x)|d\lambda=0 ?$$

I see the striking similarity to [Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), if one could use $\displaystyle\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_E f_k(x) d\lambda=\int_E f(x) d\lambda$ to find some majorant $g$ for our $f_k$ it would be true, especially it would be true when the $f_k$ converge against $f$ from below.

Comment: Or, on the other hand, to find a counterexample you should look for a sequence with no integrable majorant.

Comment: Yes I tried that, however the problem is that the integrals still have to converge... and all $f_k$ have to be integrable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $f_k$ converges to $f$ pointwise almost everywhere,    $f_k$ and $f$ are non-negative, and $\int  f_k \rightarrow \int  f $.

Note that, since the $f_k$ and $f$ are nonnegative:
$$| f_k-f\,|\le  f_k + f \quad \Rightarrow\quad f_k + f -|f_k-f\,|\ge 0.$$

By [Fatou's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma):
$$
\tag{1}\liminf_{k\to \infty} \int (  f_k + f -|f_k-f\,|\,)\ \ge \int \liminf_{k\to \infty}  \,(f_k + f -|f_k-f\,|)\,.
$$

Since $\int f_k\rightarrow\int f$, we have
 $$ \tag{2}\liminf_{k\to \infty} \int ( f_k + f -|f_k-f\,|\,)=
2\int  f -\limsup_{k\to \infty}\int|f_k-f\,|. $$

Since $f_k\rightarrow  f$ almost everywhere, we have
$$ \tag{3}\int \liminf_{k\to \infty} \, (f_k + f -|f_k-f\,|\,)= \int  2 f. $$

Substituting the expressions on the right hand sides of (2) and (3) into (1) gives:
$$
2\int  f -\limsup_{k\to \infty}\int|f_k-f\thinspace|\ge\int 2 f\ ;
$$whence
$$
\limsup_{k\to \infty}\int|f_k-f|\le0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $g_k^+:=(f_k-f)_+$ and $g_k^-:=(f-f_k)_+$, so $|f-f_k|=g_k^+ + g_k^-$ and $f_k-f=g_k^+ - g_k^-$. First note that $g_k^- \le f$ since $f$ is nonnegative, and $g_k^- \to 0$ pointwise almost everywhere. By dominated convergence, $\int g_k^-\to 0$. But
$$\int (g_k^+ + g_k^-) = \int(f_k-f+2g_k^-) = \int f_k - \int f + 2\int g_k^- \to 0$$