# Question on Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convergence in $L^1$ norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83208/convergence-in-l1-norm)
>   [Convergence of Lebesgue integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88971/convergence-of-lebesgue-integrals)

let $f$ and $f_n,n\geq 1$ be integrable functions on $X$. Suppose that $f_n \to f$ a.e. on $X$ as $n\to \infty$, and $\int_X f_n d\mu \to \int_X fd\mu$ as $n\to \infty$. Show that if every $f_n \geq 0$ a.e. on $X$, then $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_X |f_n -f|d\mu  = 0 .$$

Please how do I begin? Thanks

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88971/convergence-of-lebesgue-integrals/88991#88991). But for just a hint: Apply Fatou's Lemma to the  sequence with terms $f_k+f-|f_k-f|$.

Comment: @DavidMitra. Thanks for the link. But I don't know if $f \gt 0$. I only know that $f_n \gt 0$.

Comment: @Dan If $f_n\ge 0$ a.e. for each $n$ and if $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e., then $f\ge0$ a.e..

Comment: @DavidMitra That was my concern, Thank you.

Comment: I think this is and exact duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/108313/8271)

Comment: And all [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/83208/8271) sort of questions can be answered by [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/51502/8271)